# Crack .DLL to change ComponentOne WebGrid to .Net DataGrid in ASP.Net 1.1 application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, componentone

Ok, I'm just going to redo this question altogether. We have an old .Net 1.1 application written in VB.Net that is actually part of our old company gateway and it connects to a SQL Server 2000 database. It's currently using a webgrid from ComponentOne that just will not work anymore. (And I can't update because they have been bought out by GrapeCity.) What I'm trying to do is crack the .dll open and change from using the ComponentOne grid to the .Net DataGrid. I have successfully used a .Net decompiler to open it, but I don't know how to, or what to change, while I have it open. Please know, I have tried DotPeek, JustDecompile from Telerik, dnSpy, ILSpy, Dile, .Net Reflector, DotNetResolver (just found today), you name it. Also, I had to install XP in a virtual machine and install VS 2003 just so I can work on this crazy old project. We can't just ditch this old app just yet because we have a lot of clients that still use this application. Has **ANYONE** ever done anything like this before?! You know, changing from a third-party control to a regular .Net control using a decompiler? I'm desperate, PLEASE help me if you have!!

Comment: a "decompiler" wont help you change the component out, it will give you code to rebuild the project however

Comment: Ok thanks @mxmissile. Hey, by the way, have you successfully pulled anything like this off? And if so, what are the steps you took to do this? If you don't mind me asking. Hey that's ok if you haven't, at least now I know that what I was trying was not going to work. I guess I'll have to just decompile back to source code and start over maybe. Thanks man. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: I assume you dont have access to the original project src files?

Comment: Yes sir, well I do have access to the wwwroot folder on the server where all the .aspx, .vb, and .resx files are at. The project was named ClientPortal when the girl that worked here built this back in 2006. So I grabbed the ClientPortal.dll file and just now put it in .Net Reflector and decompiled but it created a bunch of "resources" files.

Comment: the source files to ClientPortal.dll, which I'm assuming you dont have have. (.cs, .csproj etc)

Comment: Hmm, now that I look at it a little closer, there is the ClientPortal.vbproj file along with the .sln and .suo files in there as well. I guess she uploaded all those files when she built this project. Sorry @mxmissile, I've been out of the development loop for a while. (-: Been working metal trades last several years.

Comment: If the project source files are all intact and compiles. You should be able to just replace the grid in the webform designer. Obviously would take some wireing up in the codebehind. This is your best route to persue, using a decompiler and trying to rebuild the dll from that is going to be an uphill battle that will be hard to win.

Comment: Yep, @mxmissle, that's what I'm going to do. I know what you're saying about trying to decompile and rebuild the dll. I don't think that would work out very well. I'm just gonna grab all the files from the server, then just create a new project named ClientPortal, and copy of the files in there and see where I can go from there. Thanks man, I really believe you have steered me in the right direction.